About the derivative of the conditional Rényi entropy
Preliminary considerations:
In the paper unifying framework of information measures  the conditional exponential entropy (see equation 29) is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) = E_y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{equation}
while the exponential entropy (see equation 9) is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\alpha}(x)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{equation}
So taking the log we have
\begin{equation}
\log \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) =\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x}^{\alpha}(x)\,dx\right)
\end{equation}
which is the Renyi entropy given by equation (6). We can then conclude that
\begin{equation}
\log \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) = R_{\alpha}(X) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x}^{\alpha}(x)\,dx\right)
\end{equation}
Then we can write
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X) = e^{R_{\alpha}(X)}
\end{equation}
We now consider the conditional exponential entropy given in the paper by equation (31).
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) = E_y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x|y}^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{equation}
Taking the $\log$ of both sides:
\begin{equation}
\log \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(X|Y) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log E_y\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x|y}^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)
\end{equation}
Please note that the right hand side is different from the conditional Renyi entropy given by equation (18) which is
\begin{equation}
R_{\alpha}(X|Y) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}  E_y\left(\log \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x|y}^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)
\end{equation}
Now my question: I would like to compute the first derivative of $R_{\alpha}(X|Y)$ with respect to $\alpha$. This is my attempt. We can write:
\begin{equation}
\frac {d R_{\alpha}(X|Y)}{d \alpha} = \frac{d}{d \alpha} \left[ \frac{1}{1-\alpha}  E_y\left(\log \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{x|y}^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right)\right]=
\frac{d}{d \alpha} \left[ \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{y} f_{y}(y) \left(\log \int_{x} f_{x|y}^{\alpha}(x|y)\,dx\right ) dy \right]
\end{equation}
Since $f(x,y)=f(x|y) f(y)$ we can write:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac {d R_{\alpha}(X|Y)}{d \alpha} = \frac{d}{d \alpha} \left[ \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \int_{y} f(y) \left(\log f_{y}^{-\alpha}(y)\int_{x} f^{\alpha}(x,y)\,dx\right ) dy \right]=\\
&\frac{\int {f_y}(y) \left(\log \left(\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \, dx\right)-\alpha  \log ({f_y}(y))\right) \, dy}{(\alpha -1)^2}-\frac{\int
\left(\frac{{f_y}(y) \int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \log ({f_{xy}}(x,y)) \, dx}{\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \, dx}-{f_y}(y) \log ({f_y}(y))\right) \, dy}{\alpha -1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now using the definitions of differential entropy for the random variable and the fact that
\begin{equation}
\int {f_y}(y) \log \left(\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha} \, dx\right) \, dy=(1-\alpha) R_{\alpha}(x|y)-\alpha H(y)
\end{equation}
So:
\begin{equation}
(1- \alpha) \frac {d R_{\alpha}(X|Y)}{d \alpha}-R_{\alpha}(X|Y)=H(Y)+\int \frac{{f_y}(y) \int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \log({f_{xy}}(x,y)) \, dx}{\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \, dx}\, dy
\end{equation}
Is this equation correct?

Once I reverified all the calculations, I concluded that the previously obtained result was correct. Indeed, it is possible to see that when $\lim_{\alpha \to 1}$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha \to 1} -R_{\alpha}(X|Y)=H(Y)+\lim_{\alpha \to 1} \int \frac{{f_y}(y) \int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \log({f_{xy}}(x,y)) \, dx}{\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \, dx}\, dy
\end{equation}
The first term reduces to $R_{1}(X|Y)=H(X|Y)$ while
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha \to 1} \int \frac{{f_y}(y) \int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \log({f_{xy}}(x,y)) \, dx}{\int {f_{xy}}(x,y)^{\alpha } \, dx}\, dy =\int \frac{{f_y}(y) \int {f_{xy}}(x,y) \log({f_{xy}}(x,y)) \, dx}{f_{y}(y)}\, dy = -H(X,Y)
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
H(X,Y)=H(Y)+H(X|Y)
\end{equation}
